# Keystone.js + i18n. Get current locale before rendering view

Tags: node.js, internationalization, keystonejs

I'm trying to include i18n in keystone.js app. I'm doing it like in this example https://gist.github.com/JedWatson/9191081, and it works, but my problem is to get current locale in view. I'm using a middleware for setting locale by url param:

```
// middleware.js
exports.setLocale = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.lang) {
        req.setLocale(req.params.lang);
    }
    else
        res.redirect('/ru/');
    next();
};

// index.js
keystone.pre('render', middleware.setLocale);
```

and routing

```
app.get('/:lang/', routes.views.index);
app.get('/:lang/blog/:category?', routes.views.blog);
app.get('/:lang/blog/post/:post', routes.views.post);
...
```

Default locale is 'ru'. But in my view

```
view.on('render', function (next) {
    console.log('on render', req.getLocale());
    next();
});

console.log('before render', req.getLocale());
view.render('blog');
```

on route `/en/blog` it outputs

```
------------------------------------------------
KeystoneJS Started:
qalqan is ready on default port 3000
------------------------------------------------

before render ru
on render en
GET /en/blog 304 373ms
```

So, as i understand, locale is changed after varibales sended to view. Is threre any way to set it before rendering? I know, that i can get it by req.params from url param `lang` in each view, but i want do it by middleware for all views.

Comment: try `console.log('on render', getLocale());`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Since i18n version 0.7.0 your code should work.

It seems a bit counter-intuitive, but I think you should not touch the routing to avoid repetition of the lang parameter.

You are exactly on the right path though and here is what I did:

```
// routes/middleware.js

exports.detectLang = function(req, res, next) {
    var match = req.url.match(/^\/(de|en)([\/\?].*)?$/i);

    if (match) {
        req.setLocale(match[1]);
        // Make locale available in template
        // (necessary until i18n 0.6.x)
        res.locals.locale = req.getLocale();
        // reset the URL for routing
        req.url = match[2] || '/';
    } (else) {
        // Here you can redirect to default locale if you want
    }

    next();
}
```

Now just use the middleware before all the other res.locals are defined:

```
// routes/index.js

keystone.pre('routes', i18n.init);
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.detectLang);
```

Now you can prepend all URLs with `'/' + res.locals.locale` and the user will keep their locale everywhere around your app.